# Can we integrate Apache solr search in Magento Community Edition

Tags: magento, solr

I wanted to know can we integrate apache solr search in magento community edition 1.7.0.2
Till now I tried this link for installing solr [solr apache installation on windows](http://beckelman.net/2011/02/22/setup-apache-solr-on-windows-with-jetty-running-as-a-service-via-nssm).I was able to install solr using this tutorial.But how  can I integrate solr search with magento?

Comment: Did you find Solution for Magento CE Edition. I am using Magento 2.1.3 CE. Please provide info if you found any solution .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only EE support Solr integration from the scratch, but there are some Community third-party modules available:

- http://code.google.com/p/magento-solr/
- http://solrgento.de/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-bridge-search.html

Or build youself an extension based on one of the PHP Solr librarys:

- https://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/
- http://www.solarium-project.org/

Comment: Looks like it might be here now: https://code.google.com/p/magento-community-edition-solr/

Comment: Google Translation link for the solrgento.de site (commercial software) - http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&prev=_dd&u=http://solrgento.de/

Comment: The google code project appears to be empty, at least in terms of git. Instructions: https://code.google.com/p/magento-community-edition-solr/source/checkout  But when you "git clone https://code.google.com/p/magento-community-edition-solr/" it says "warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository."

Comment: @TobiasZander or others, do you have any tips on using Solarium with Magento? I am still rather unfamiliar with Composer and it's not blindingly obvious to me how to integrate that library with Magento.

Comment: Can anyone please answer this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318655/how-to-configure-integrate-apache-solr-6-5-0-into-magento-2-1-3-ce-edition

Answer (score 4):

magentix/Solr, see https://github.com/magentix/Solr, uses a pretty simple strategy on updating the search index. There will be limitations for larger data sets (or the need to have a large amount of ram). It simply writes the content of the catalogsearch_fulltext table into the Solr index holding the whole data in the memory. This has been observed in version 1.1.0.

solrgento, see  http://solrgento.de/,  uses a more sophisticated approach on solr index updates by a close integration in the Magento index update process. It can handle even really large sets of products and attributes without problems. The support for the module is quity responsive.

Answer (score 2):

I have just released a brand new free Magento extension based on Solarium.
It is much better quality than the Magentix Solr.
Auto correct on search terms is supported.

[Extension on Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/22478/)

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium)